# If condition for two vertical tests and two tables in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

i have two vertical tests in two different columns now i want to merge two tables data into one.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP([@[Incl. Service Product Line]],DependProd,2,FALSE),"Included Service Missing")

=IFNA(VLOOKUP([@[Incl. Service Product Line]],Addons,2,FALSE),"Addons Missing")
```

when i tried to merge these two formulas into one column i'm facing issues
i'm using two logical tests in one formula but the formula is pulling only one set of data.

```
=IF(OR([Path]="Base",[Path]="Add on"),(IFNA(VLOOKUP([@[Incl. Service Product Line]],Addons,2,FALSE),"Addons Missing")),IFNA(VLOOKUP([@[Incl. Service Product Line]],DependProd,2,FALSE),"Included Service Missing"))
```

this is the formula which i have trouble with.
if the path is "Base" the data should be pulled from DependProd table and if the path is "Add on" then i need the data to be pulled from Addons table, but the formula is pulling only one table data

Comment: Can you include a piece of sample data with desired output? Always easier to picture what you trying to achieve with some visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Without any example data, this is how you might consider structuring the data and using vlookup:

[image]

But you can also consider index() with match():

[image]

Comment: Thank you, to simplify. If path is add on then return values from add on table for all other paths return values from Included table