# Excel Dependent Dropdown

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In total I have 3 dropdowns, 1st is Country, 2nd is Product and 3rd is Price.

Based on country selection from 1st dropdown, the product name should be listed in 2nd dropdown and their respective price in 3rd dropdown (which may have different price values in different stores, within same country so dropdown with different prices is required).

I tried to us Indirect formula based on country but I can populate only products in 2nd dropdown. But price cannot be populated with same condition in 3rd dropdown.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So populate the 2nd dropdown list from a set of cells using index() and match(), choose the correct version based on the country choice.

Comment: See a similar thing I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56824366/4961700

Answer (score 0):

So, quick example:
[image]

The data validation for the country drives the match then index gets the result.